# Не передается знак "+" в запросе к VK API

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, vkscript

В VK API есть метод execute (https://vk.com/dev/execute). При передачи параметра code не передается знак "+". Например, имеется такой код:

```
code = 'return 1 + 1;'
requests.get(API_URL + 'execute?' + 'v=5.34&access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN + '&code=' + code).json()
```

В ответе на запрос перечислены переданные параметры и в частности параметр code:

`{'value': 'return 1   1;', 'key': 'code'}` (обратите внимание, что + отсутсвует).

и ошибка:

`'error_msg': "Unable to compile code:  ';' expected, '1' found in line 1"`

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед передачей параметров через URL к ним следует применять [url-кодирование](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).